# Java GC Young/Old 100% but to/from 0%

Tags: java, garbage-collection

The following is seen in a hs_err_pid####.log file. 
The eden space is full as well as the old space, but the from/to space is at 0%

```
Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 197,652K, used 190,955K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000f8000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 190,956K, 99% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000f657fff8,0x00000000f6580000)
  from space 6,646K, 0% used [0x00000000f7080000,0x00000000f7080000,0x00000000f7700000)
  to   space 11,364K, 0% used [0x00000000f6580000,0x00000000f6580000,0x00000000f7080000)
 ParOldGen       total 699,397K, used 699,341K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000eab00000)
  object space 699,332K, 99% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000eaaffff8,0x00000000eab00000)
 Metaspace       used 71522K, capacity 76253K, committed 129276K, reserved 1126500K
  class space    used 7619K, capacity 11188K, committed 52466K, reserved 1048576K
```

Could this occur when dealing with LARGE Arrays, HashTable or whatever?
Is it possible that when a minor GC occurs, the from/to space is too small to handle the object size and as a result it goes straight to the old space?

Has there been a common cause that people have encountered when seeing this type of behavior?

Comment: Yep. That is definitely a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to run a [Eclipse MAT](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.mat) or similar tool and check which object is taking up the memory.

I had faced a similar issue in Kafka and it was due to a memory leak related to managed bean. In my case the Beans were very small in size, but a lot in number.

So your Old gen can get filled up regardless of the size of the object, as long as JVM thinks it needs to be kept alive.

Comment: Thanks, the JVM has the memory heap dump on crash flag set. Waiting for the next occurrence.